# Insert DOB in mysql from laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, date

i have made a form with three different input fields i.e day, month and year and i need to insert it into database in 'dob' column in the type 'date'. how can i insert them all with date format in one column.

```html
<div>
 <input class="birthdayInput" type="number" name="birthday_day" id="birthday_day" size="2"  maxlength="2" value=""/>

<input class="birthdayInput" type="number" name="birthday_month" 
 id="birthday_month"  size="2" maxlength="2" value=""/>

 <input class="birthdayInput" type="number" name="birthday_year" id="birthday_year" size="4"
 maxlength="4" value=""/>

</div>
```

Comment: Hint: Combine them into `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: $formData = $formRequest->all();

        $dob = $formRequest->get('birthday_day') .'-' . $formRequest->get('birthday_month') . '-'. $formRequest->get('birthday_year');

        $formData['dob'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dob));

so i did this, now how can i insert?

Comment: 1. You need to use the format tadman specified. 2. Show the code you've got and where you're stuck. 3. Don't post it in the comments, edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $da $request->birthday_day. ' ' . $request->birthday_month.' '. $request->birthday_year
```

You Can try this.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use a date input in html, this will allow the user to choose a date in one hit.

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('birthday.store') }}">
     <input type="date" name="birthday">
 </form
```

then when it hits your controller format it with Carbon like so:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $birthday = Carbon::parse($request->birthday)->format('Y-m-d');
    //store to database here
}
```

You can store that into your table now, make sure the column is of date type

```
$table->date('birth_date');
```

This is the way i'd do it. Just a bit easier all round.

If you want to keep your way just concatenate each date segment like so:

```
$birthday = $request->year . '-' . $request->month . '-' . $request->day;
```

Dates have to be YYYY-MM-DD when inserting into date column sql

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Colin said

Go ahead and add this to your model:

```
protected $dates = ['birth_date'];
```